# Regex and String Manipulation Techniques

Tags: java, regex

Given that an input String may be specified as follows:

- read(xpath(‘...’))  or
- xpath(‘...’)        or
- ...

Where ... just holds some xpath expression, for example,`/comment/text`

All I really want is the xpath expression; what would be an efficient way to in general extract this value given the three possible valid patterns that could be specified.

Also, I am implementing this in Java.

Comment: You don't need regex for that. startsWith() and substring() are sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the basic example, it matches xpath part in both of your string examples:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Untitled {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "read(xpath('...'))";
    String result = null;
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("xpath\\(\'(.*?)\'\\)");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        result = matcher.group(1);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped you posted some code but you can use String Split. Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

If you are sure to have xpath('') , then you can use xpath(' as your regex and strip the string and gather the data inside it until it hits another ' (apostrophe).

I hope this gives you an idea.